# angularjs fail to custom validate model array value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I don't get this sorted out. I try to add validation (for form submit deactivation if invalid) wether an array contains items or not. i tried using a custom directive but it never gets called when the model updates :( 
as the angular stuff is rendered inside a play applications template and the form is not defined within my scope I cannot do some easy form invalidation.

what i try to achieve is invalidating the form until some category has been added to $scope.app.categories thereby deactivating the submit button which is also not within my scope.

here comes the code (angular version 1.2.23):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="app.categories" name="size" custom />
<input id="tagsinput" type="text" ng-model="new.category" on-keyup="disabled" keys="[13]"/>
<a class="btn" ng-click="addCategory()">Add</a>

// loading of app happens above this is the contoller function
    $scope.addCategory = function () {
        $scope.app.categories.push({name: $scope.new.category});
        $scope.new.category = "";
    }

app.directive('custom', function() {
    return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(val1, val2, val3, val4) {
            // not even gets called would like to validate app.categories here :(
            console.log(true);
        });
    }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$formatters`, but for validation you should use `$validators`. Instead of your line starting with `ctrl.$formatters`, try the following:

```
ctrl.$validators.yourValidatorName = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    console.log("Validator is called.");
    return true; // This means validation passed.
};
```

You can find this in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). Also do not forget to add the directive to the HTML element, so in your case `<input ... custom>`. To disable a submit button if validation fails, use `<input type="submit" data-ng-disabled="formName.$invalid">`.

Comment: $validators is undefined - maybe angular 1.2.23 is missing this?!

Comment: also submit button is outside my scope im just a piece of play template where the outer form and button can't be changed...

Comment: @xstring you’re right, validators was added in 1.3 and is unavailable in 1.2 ([here’s what is available](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)). Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @jackweirdy yes finally figured it out back then. Thanks for the reply.